# nm-applet error messages in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Whenever I run a terminal (which is always) it gets full of many, many nm-applet messages like this:

> (nm-applet:3693): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:04:36.418: Can't set a parent on
>   widget which has a parent
>
> (nm-applet:3693): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 18:04:36.424: gtk_widget_destroy:
>   assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

I would have thought these types of messages would be redirected to `.xsession-errors` but for some reason that file is 0 length. The file permissions are `644` so I don't think that's the issue.
I don't know what's controlling the nm-applet startup. (If I knew that I could redirect errors to `.xsession-errors` or `/dev/null`, but.)
Anyone know how to fix this? It is extremely intrusive and annoying.
TIA

Comment: The errors come up as soon as I launch the terminal, before I've even typed anything in. I don't have any network widget installed, just what came with  NetworkManager.

Comment: OK, I found the solution to the problem. I found a line in ~/.bashrc left over from a previous installation of a different distribution:
dbus-launch nm-applet &
Removing this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer: I had installed Ubuntu on a machine on which I had been running a different distribution (Gentoo) with no systemd or other Ubuntu init stuff. When I installed Ubuntu, I kept the `/home` partition from before. In the `.bashrc` file in `$HOME`, was a line

```
dbus-launch nm-applet &
```

That was the cause of all my problems. I got rid of it and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a known bug. Please add your "This affects me to" to give it higher priority.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1751673